# "conda list" will correctly identify pip installed gunicorn, but "conda list -e" option it does not

Tags: anaconda, gunicorn

Windows 10
Latest Anaconda3 build

I created a virtual environment using conda. 
I activited this environment (BTW, you must use CMD, as it will not switch if you're using powershell)

Now, gunicorn package cannot be installed using conda (unkown package), therefore I've needed to use pip. Pip has installed the package successfully.

When I do "conda list" I see the package:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3\envs\HerokuApp:
#
click                     6.6                      py35_0
flask                     0.11.1                   py35_0
gunicorn                  19.6.0                    <pip>
itsdangerous              0.24                     py35_0
jinja2                    2.8                      py35_1
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_2
mkl                       11.3.3                        1
nltk                      3.2.1                    py35_0
numpy                     1.11.1                   py35_0
pandas                    0.18.1              np111py35_0
pip                       8.1.2                    py35_0
python                    3.5.1                         5
python-dateutil           2.5.3                    py35_0
pytz                      2016.4                   py35_0
scikit-learn              0.17.1              np111py35_1
scipy                     0.17.1              np111py35_1
setuptools                23.0.0                   py35_0
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    0
werkzeug                  0.11.10                  py35_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
```

But when I run "conda list -e" for output to a requirement.txt file (for Heroku), the package is not listed

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: win-64
click=6.6=py35_0
flask=0.11.1=py35_0
itsdangerous=0.24=py35_0
jinja2=2.8=py35_1
markupsafe=0.23=py35_2
mkl=11.3.3=1
nltk=3.2.1=py35_0
numpy=1.11.1=py35_0
pandas=0.18.1=np111py35_0
pip=8.1.2=py35_0
python=3.5.1=5
python-dateutil=2.5.3=py35_0
pytz=2016.4=py35_0
scikit-learn=0.17.1=np111py35_1
scipy=0.17.1=np111py35_1
setuptools=23.0.0=py35_0
six=1.10.0=py35_0
vs2015_runtime=14.0.25123=0
werkzeug=0.11.10=py35_0
wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
```

Does anyone know what/why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly on the what/why but if you use `conda env export` you'll get the pip installed packages too. Not in the requirement.txt format but it could be useful.

BTW I do see a py3.5 version of `gunicorn` for windows over [here](https://anaconda.org/phumke/gunicorn) if that helps.  It is only version 19.3.0 but you can conda install it via `conda install -c phumke gunicorn=19.3.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the conda version